# Javascript page reload while maintaining current window position

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I refresh the page using Javascript without the page returning to
the top.

My page refreshes using a timer but the problem is it goes back to the top every time it reloads. It should be able to retain the current position of the page as it reloads.

P.S.
Additional mouse events are welcome if necessary to be a part of your suggestion.
I'm actually thinking of `#idname` to target on refresh but my HTML elements don't have IDs, only classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use JavaScript, this code will do the trick.

```
var cookieName = "page_scroll";
var expdays = 365;

// An adaptation of Dorcht's cookie functions.

function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
    if (!expires) expires = new Date();
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + 
        ((expires == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString()) +
        ((path    == null) ? "" : "; path=" + path) +
        ((domain  == null) ? "" : "; domain=" + domain) +
        ((secure  == null) ? "" : "; secure");
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var arg = name + "=";
    var alen = arg.length;
    var clen = document.cookie.length;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < clen) {
        var j = i + alen;
        if (document.cookie.substring(i, j) == arg) {
            return getCookieVal(j);
        }
        i = document.cookie.indexOf(" ", i) + 1;
        if (i == 0) break;
    }
    return null;
}

function getCookieVal(offset) {
    var endstr = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
    if (endstr == -1) endstr = document.cookie.length;
    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, endstr));
}

function deleteCookie(name, path, domain) {
    document.cookie = name + "=" +
        ((path   == null) ? "" : "; path=" + path) +
        ((domain == null) ? "" : "; domain=" + domain) +
        "; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-00 00:00:01 GMT";
}

function saveScroll() {
    var expdate = new Date();
    expdate.setTime(expdate.getTime() + (expdays*24*60*60*1000)); // expiry date

    var x = document.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft;
    var y = document.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;
    var data = x + "_" + y;
    setCookie(cookieName, data, expdate);
}

function loadScroll() {
    var inf = getCookie(cookieName);
    if (!inf) { return; }
    var ar = inf.split("_");
    if (ar.length == 2) {
        window.scrollTo(parseInt(ar[0]), parseInt(ar[1]));
    }
}
```

This works by using a cookie to remember the scroll position.

Now just add

```
onload="loadScroll()" onunload="saveScroll()"
```

to your body tag and all will be well.

**Source(s):** http://www.huntingground.freeserve.co.uk/main/mainfram.htm?../scripts/cookies/scrollpos.htm

Comment: Is there a way how to make this work with page loaded inside an ´iframe´? I have google document in preview mode added to site with an ´iframe´ and I need to refresh it for user every x seconds, without messing up with his position in document.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a certain set of specific sections of the page that are possible initial "scroll to" points, then you can assign those sections CSS ids and refresh the page with an appended ID hash at the end. For example, `window.location = http://example.com#section2` will reload the page and automatically scroll it down to the element with the id "section2".

If it's not that specific, you can grab the current scroll position prior to refresh using jQuery's `.scrollTop()` method on the `window`: `$(window).scrollTop()`. You can then append this to the refresh URL, and include JS on the page that checks for this in order to automatically scroll to the correct position upon page load:

**Grab current scroll position**

```
var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
window.location = 'http://example.com#' + currentScroll;
```

**JS that must run when DOM is ready in order to check for a currentScroll hash**

```
$(function(){
    if(window.location.hash !== ''){
        var scrollPos = parseInt(window.location.hash.substring(1),10);
        $(window).scrollTo(scrollPos);
    }
});
```

If you don't like the idea of modifying the URL in the address bar (because you really want to hide what you're doing from the user for some reason), you could store the `scrollTo()` value in a cookie instead of the URL.

Comment: I really like this quick hack. Now I think about it, local/dom storage might be another idea you could use. Give it a google.

Comment: The problem with local storage is that it's only available via HTML5. Until ie8 dies, relying on HTML5 isn't a good idea if your user base will include people using ie8.

Comment: Sorry I was thinking about the [window.name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#window.name) capability that was kind of useful before tabs became a regular thing.

Comment: Also local storage is not supported on iPad Private mode ... if you are supporting the device option too

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a cookie based method:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var refreshPeriod = 120; // 120 Seconds

            function refresh()
            {
                document.cookie = 'scrollTop=' + filterScrollTop();
                document.cookie = 'scrollLeft=' + filterScrollLeft();
                document.location.reload(true);
            }

            function getCookie(name)
            {
                var start = document.cookie.indexOf(name + "=");
                var len = start + name.length + 1;

                if(((!start) && (name != document.cookie.substring(0, name.length))) || start == -1)
                    return null;

                var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", len);

                if(end == -1)
                    end = document.cookie.length;

                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(len, end));
            }

            function deleteCookie(name)
            {
                document.cookie = name + "=" + ";expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT";
            }

            function setupRefresh()
            {
                var scrollTop = getCookie("scrollTop");
                var scrollLeft = getCookie("scrollLeft");

                if (!isNaN(scrollTop))
                {
                    document.body.scrollTop = scrollTop;
                    document.documentElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
                }

                if (!isNaN(scrollLeft))
                {
                    document.body.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
                    document.documentElement.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;
                }

                deleteCookie("scrollTop");
                deleteCookie("scrollLeft");

                setTimeout("refresh()", refreshPeriod * 1000);
            }

            function filterResults(win, docEl, body)
            {
                var result = win ? win : 0;

                if (docEl && (!result || (result > docEl)))
                    result = docEl;

                return body && (!result || (result > body)) ? body : result;
            }

            // Setting the cookie for vertical position
            function filterScrollTop()
            {
                var win = window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : 0;
                var docEl = document.documentElement ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : 0;
                var body = document.body ? document.body.scrollTop : 0;
                return filterResults(win, docEl, body);
            }

            // Setting the cookie for horizontal position
            function filterScrollLeft()
            {
                var win = window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : 0;
                var docEl = document.documentElement ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : 0;
                var body = document.body ? document.body.scrollLeft : 0;
                return filterResults(win, docEl, body);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="setupRefresh()">
        <!-- content here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

or you can do it with a form method:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Saves scroll position
            function scroll(value)
            {
                var hidScroll = document.getElementById('hidScroll');
                hidScroll.value = value.scrollTop;
            }

            // Moves scroll position to saved value
            function scrollMove(el)
            {
                var hidScroll = document.getElementById('hidScroll');
                document.getElementById(el).scrollTop = hidScroll.value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="scrollMove('divScroll');" onunload="document.forms(0).submit()";>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="hidScroll" name="a"><br />
            <div id="divScroll" onscroll="scroll(this);"
                 style="overflow:auto;height:100px;width:100px;">
                <!-- content here -->
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just depends on your application's requirements and restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend refreshing only the part of the page you are interested  in changing, using ajax. I mean, just replacing the content using javascript depending on the response of the ajax call. I would say you take a look at jQuery's [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) methods.

If you can give more information about what you are trying to do maybe I can be of more assistance. Anyway, I hope this helps a little bit.

Cheers!

Comment: Ok sir, page i want to refresh is actually a part of the page already since its inside <iframe> tag. Now, i refresh the content of the <iframe> using a javascript included on its header (<iframe> page content <head> tag). The page inside <iframe> loads a table comming from my database. It loads by default the current data for the day or the data of a selected date. parameters for my database query are found on the GET variables of the page. Every time the page refresh, i retain the GET variables in the URL so that it would load the page with the same data.

Comment: I have read that you are on PHP, I really don't know anything on PHP, but can you make an HTTP GET to the call that only returns the talbe data in JSON format? that way you only need to make that call from javascript and refresh the table.