# maintain scroll position when return back to the page

Tags: php, scroll

**Background:**
I have page with a table inside  that contains more than 1000 data. By default the table will display 300 data at first. When user scroll till the bottom of the table, there is a button that can be clicked. Every time the button is clicked another 300 data will be loaded into the table. Each of the row has a button that can be clicked to view the details. User can click on the button, and back to previous page.

**Problem:**
When user return to previous page after clicking the button, the data will be displayed starting from the 1st again. User needs to scroll and find the position of the previous data that has been clicked.

**Question:**
How to let the browser maintain the scroll position after user return to the page without displaying the data from the beginning?

Below is the script that I used to load those data.

**php script** (table loads data from outside)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="infinitescroller">
<table height="100%" width="100%" class="tableFormat" id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <th width="6%">No</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>I.C.</th>
        <?php
        if($_SESSION['login_level'] == 'admin')
        {
        ?>
        <th>Staff in-charge</th>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>MemberCard No.</th>
        <th>Incoming Follow Up</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#infinitescroller').scrollPagination({
        nop     : 300, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
        offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
        error   : 'No More Posts!', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                    // displayed. You can change this if you want.
        delay   : 200, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                       // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
        scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                       // but will still load if the user clicks.
    });  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**table content script**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../../include/dbconnection.php");

$offset = is_numeric($_POST['offset']) ? $_POST['offset'] : die();
$postnumbers = is_numeric($_POST['number']) ? $_POST['number'] : die();

$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM lassclient WHERE 1 ".$_SESSION['cust_search']." LIMIT ".$postnumbers." OFFSET ".$offset);
$counter = $offset;

while($get_q = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $counter++;

    $sid = $get_q['salesid'];
    $pic = '';
    $called = '';
    $html = '';
    $staff_name = '';

    //get staff name
    $staff_q = mysql_query("select * from lassuser where userid = '$sid'");
    $get = mysql_fetch_array($staff_q);

    if($get_q['custpic'] != '')
    {
        $pic = '<a href="'.$get_q['custpic'].'" class="nm2" style="width:8em" target="_blank">
        <img src="'.$get_q['custpic'].'" width="20px" height="20px"/></a>';
    }

    if($get_q['called'] != '0000-00-00 00:00:00')
    {
        $called = $get_q['called']; 
    }

    if($_SESSION['login_level'] == 'admin')
    {
        $staff_name = "<td style='text-align:center; padding-left:0px'>".$get['fullname']."</td>";
        $html = "<a href=\"javascript:deleteConfirmation('".$get_q['clientname']."', '".$get_q['clientid']."')\"><img src=\"../../img/delete.png\" title=\"Delete\" width=\"18\"></a>";
    }   

    echo '<tr id="#'.$counter.'">
            <td style="text-align:center; padding-left:0px">'.$counter.'</td>
            <td>'.$get_q['clientname'].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; padding-left:0px">'.$get_q['ic'].'</td>'.$staff_name.'
            <td style="text-align:center; padding-left:0px">'.$get_q['hp'].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; padding-left:0px">'.$get_q['cardno'].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; padding-left:0px">'.$get_q['followupdate'].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center; padding-left:0px">
                <a href="editCust.php?id='.$get_q['clientid'].'&r='.$counter.'" onclick="a('.$counter.')"><img src="../../img/edit.png" title="Edit" width="18"></a>                    
            </td>
          </tr>';
}
?>
```

The format that I want is kinda of similar with yahoo mail. Just that yahoo mail uses infinity scroll to scroll the mailbox, instead of clicking.

Comment: You need a plugin that make use of history API. In this way the url change while scrolling. For example [this](https://github.com/outdooricon/infinite-scroll-with-history). Read more [here](http://eviltrout.com/2013/02/16/infinite-scrolling-that-works.html).

Comment: @redreggae is there any sample on how to use it?

Comment: This was only an example..I didn't test it. But look at [test/index.html](https://github.com/outdooricon/infinite-scroll-with-history/blob/master/test/index.html). The commented `pathParse` should do it.

Comment: You may want to check following thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577897/javascript-page-reload-while-maintaining-current-window-position