# How to prevent page scrolling to top, after hyperlink clicked, and after server based refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this question has been asked quite a bit, but I am unable to stop my page scrolling to the top.

I have numerous links like

```
<a href="myApp/Delete/1">Delete</a>
<a href="myApp/Delete/2">Delete</a>
<a href="myApp/Delete/3">Delete</a>
<a href="myApp/Delete/4">Delete</a>
<a href="myApp/Delete/5">Delete</a>
```

When I click on one of these the server action is invoked, and then the page refreshes, to the top.

I tried, putting the following in the header, to no avail:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
  });
</script>
```

I tried adding "Return false" as:

```
onClick="Return false;"
```

But this stop the server action being invoked

I have seen references to:

```
    <a href="#!">Delete</a>
```

But then I need to handle the call to the server action.

I would be most grateful for some advice on this please.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Changed to Delete, to make clearer. So if record deleted, I would page to retain its scroll position, rather than scroll to the top.

EDIT2:

[Solution I found at Sitepoint, for the benefit of all. This works.](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?625439-Maintaining-Scroll-Box-Position-Upon-Page-Refresh)

Comment: I'm not following, if you click the link. Your page refreshes thus being at the top of the page. Unless you're want to do something other than loading the "myApp/Select/1" page

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Okay, I may not be clear enough. Imagine they were deletes, and I had 30 rows, and I wish the page to retain its scroll position, having deleted a record.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577897/javascript-page-reload-while-maintaining-current-window-position?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Thanks, Just found something very similar, which works. Put as EDIT2

Answer (score -1):

You can easly set class on all  your links , and attach click event with jQuery , and return false
   example

```
$('.myLink').click(function(e) {        
     return false; 

});
```

another solution but you told what this doesnt work is the set return false directly on a element

`<a href="myApp/Delete/5" onclick="return false">Delete</a>`

Comment: 1. This is just code without any explanation what or why it does stuff. 2. Both `return false` and `e.preventDefault()` would do the same thing in stopping the browser of going to the link. 3. Even then, `e.preventDefault()` would do absolutely nothing, since it's unreachable code - the function returns and exits before it hits that.