# Reload page without scrolling up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am submitting some data with `jQuery` via `ajax`, and on success I am refreshing page with

```
document.location.reload(true);
```

Is there any way to prevent page scrolling back top the top. I did a bit of research and it seems possible to fool Chrome. I also came across the following function, but not really sure where to place it in order for it to work.

```
if (window.location.hash) { 
    //bind to scroll function
    $(document).scroll( function() {
        var hash = window.location.hash
        var hashName = hash.substring(1, hash.length);
        var element;

        //if element has this id then scroll to it
        if ($(hash).length != 0) {
            element = $(hash);
        }
        //catch cases of links that use anchor name
        else if ($('a[name="' + hashName + '"]').length != 0)
        {
            //just use the first one in case there are multiples
            element = $('a[name="' + hashName + '"]:first');
        }

        //if we have a target then go to it
        if (element != undefined) {
            window.scrollTo(0, element.position().top);
        }
        //unbind the scroll event
        $(document).unbind("scroll");
    });
}
```

Since I'm refreshing this page, after submitting via a click on an element, shall i attach it somehow to `.click` event?

Comment: This has been asked many times, please just look around on Stack Overflow

Comment: Im not too sure, but have you looked at `preventDefault`

Comment: why not giving back the whole page-html for the ajax-fn, and inject it dynamically, rebind everything.. without even having the need of reloading after all? well something like that yells after angular/react.. ^^

Comment: I actually considered .remove('em to refresh') and adding new content with jQuery. Just seems a bit convoluted. Or I may grab .scrollTop() send it with ajax post and then return back on success and load... :)\

Comment: what is the purpose of reloading the page - why not simply reload the content of the changed div based on the Ajax returned data and leave hte page where it was upon submission of hte Ajax?

Comment: This was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7577970/4672534).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use cookie to do it.

Before you reload the page, add cookie for last position of scrollTop:

```
$.cookie('last-scroll-top', $(window).scrollTop());
document.location.reload(true);
```

And when the page reload, we read the cookie, scroll and delete cookie:

```
var lastScrollTop = $.cookie('last-scroll-top');
if (lastScrollTop) {
    $(window).scrollTop(lastScrollTop);
    $.removeCookie('last-scroll-top');
}
```

Comment: Not really, this will turn into a endless refresh loop.

Comment: @Thielicious Did you delete cookie before reload. You should do it.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

In your AJAX `success` add/adjust the following:

```
window.location.hash = "#sp" + $(window).scrollTop();;
window.location.reload(true);
```

Then in your `document ready` or `onload`:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    var pos = hash.substring(3, hash.length); //3 is used to remove "#sp" from hash name
    if(!isNaN(pos))
        window.scrollTo(0, pos);
    }
```

**Disclaimer:** If you have valid reason to reload the entire page and not just a subsection of it in a div, the solution will work for you.

Comment: It worked for me. I did it in my cart page after saving/updating info from modal, then reflects on just the table area. Should I be worried that this may cause me some problems in performance or wherever because I loaded the entire page and not just the table area?

Comment: As long as the page isn't that data heavy, you shouldn't have a performance hit. This was probably more relevant 5 years ago when this question was asked but in this day and age you shouldn't feel a thing :-)